# Save images url to library (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**I am displaying a photo in the application following the link, how can I save this photo to my phone's library?**

```
struct RemoteImage: View {
    
    private enum LoadState {
        case loading, success, failure
    }
    
    private class Loader: ObservableObject {
        var data = Data()
        var state = LoadState.loading
        
        init(url: String) {
            guard let parsedURL = URL(string: url) else {
                fatalError("Invalid URL: \(url)")
            }
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: parsedURL) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data, data.count > 0 {
                    self.data = data
                    self.state = .success
                } else {
                    self.state = .failure
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
    
    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    var loading: Image
    var failure: Indicator
    
    var body: some View {
        selectImage()
    }
    
    init(url: String, loading: Image = Image("loadingimage").resizable(), failure: Indicator = Indicator()) {
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(url: url))
        self.loading = loading
        self.failure = failure
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder private func selectImage() -> some View {
        switch loader.state {
        case .loading:
            loading
        case .failure:
            failure
        default:
            if let image = UIImage(data: loader.data) {
                Image(uiImage: image).resizable()
            } else {
                failure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to save a photo using `.contextMenu` but by clicking on the button I get an error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
   RemoteImage(url: image.obr1)
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         .cornerRadius(15)
         .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
         .cornerRadius(15)
         
         .contextMenu {
                                                
         Button(action: {
                                                    
           let im = UIImage(named: "image.jpeg")!
           UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im, nil,nil, nil)
                                                    
           }) {

            HStack {
                                                        
            Text("Save")
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down.fill")
                                                        
  }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
I'm new to swift, thanks for any help

**I edited my question, please help if anyone knows the answer**

Answer (score 1):

Remove function and use direct code.

```
Button(action: {
    let im = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")!
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im, nil,nil, nil)
}) {
    
    HStack {
        
        Text("Save")
        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down.fill")
        
    }
}
```

Or put your function outside the Button action and call the function inside the button action.

Comment: If I remove the function, I get the error: 
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @Dmitriy That mens you don't have your image `"image.jpg"` in your app bundle

Comment: Check your assets and use ```UIImage(named:"image")``` and if possible use if let or guard let.

Comment: I still get the error

Comment: @Dmitriy have you set photo permission in plist file? Before saving image you first need to check or ask photo library permission.

Comment: No, I haven't installed it (I'm new to Swift, tell me how to do this?

Comment: <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key> ?

Comment: Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39749331/14733292

Comment: I did everything right and updated the info.plist, but I still get this error when clicking save: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I am getting an image from the link, maybe this is causing the error?

Comment: if I select a photo that is uploaded to my project, it is saved, but the photo that I receive from the link is not saved to the library

Comment: From link, you first need to download the image and then save it.

Comment: It is already downloaded and displayed in the application

Comment: I edited my question, please help if anyone knows the answer

Comment: Image.jpeg is not available in your assets

Comment: What do I need to do?